# MasterViewController of UISplitViewController not shown after rotation during full screen video playback

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController that shows the MasterViewController only when in landscape, the default.

If I start in portrait, click a button to play a video (primary function of my app), then go to full screen, then rotate into landscape, then exit full screen: the MasterViewController is not displayed.

Instead, where the master should be, it is simply black dead space. On the right side, the detail view controller is displayed correctly.

I cannot figure out why the master is not being displayed. This is with iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can helps you:
https://github.com/alexth/TBSV
Sample of how to have UINavigationBar, UITabBar and UISplitViewController in one project with correct looking transitions between orientations